# Remote Glassfish can't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, docker, glassfish

I have a web app in java-ee which is deploy localy and remotely with glassfish.
I also have a database in MySQL localized on my remote server.

When I deploy my app localy, all works fine, and my app is connect to my remote database. But, when i deploy remotely on my server, it works but my app is not connect to database.

I use docker on my server, glassfish is in a container but mysql isn't.
I deploy glassfish with payara/server-full ( instance of glassfish ):

```
sudo docker run -it -p 4848:4848 -p 8080:8080 payara/server-full
```

A friend of mine do the same thing and it works well.

Comment: Maybe you can test that : can the application connect with a local db? If it can, the error should be in the db connection reference. It is relative somehow not to the host but the installer machine. I just guessing! :)

Comment: In my code I have: `String url = "jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/ecom";`.
If i set `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecom"` instead, the result is the same.
I created a database in my local machine, and the web app deploy localy is connect to it. But for the remote web app, it doesn't work :/

Comment: If you use j2ee than you can use Database connection resources stored by the app server, initialized at deploy time by the admin. Don't use wired connection strings in the code.

Comment: Do you speak about glassfish-resources.xml file? I saw in this file this line:
`<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/ecom"/>`
How can i re-use this property in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DI in any type of container managed objects. First you have to register the connection in the app server (use an IDE or the admin console :4848) Stateless session bean is just one example.

```
package mypackage;

imports 

@Stateless
public class MyBean
{
    @Resource(lookup = "java:/app/registered_datasource_name")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void businessMethod()
    {
      try ( Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection() )
      {
        // Work with connection here
      }
      catch (SQLException e)
      {
        throw new SomeRuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: I created a new JDBC connection pool and JDBC resource linked together from admin console. The JNDI name is ecomDB. So when I do:
`@Resource(lookup = "java:/app/ecomDB")
private DataSource dataSource;
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()`
It gives me nullExceptionPointerException. How I have to initialize DataSource?
( At begin, I thank that the string was "java:/myApp/ecomDB", but it change nothing)

Comment: maybe it will help : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggjue.html

Comment: Ok thanks, it does not solve my problem but now my project is cleaner.